# From an XSD schema to Xml document. Set an attribute value

Tags: python, xml, xsd

i have an xsd schema

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="Data_Requests">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Admin">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="SystemId"/>
                        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="OSName"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="SentRequest">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="database">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="datasetRequest">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name1111"/>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Using PyXB according to xsd schema i created classes:
python pyxbgen -u schema3.xsd -m schema3

I wrote python script, but i do not know haw set value for attribute name111

```
def create_general_xml():

   rep = Data_Requests()
   rep.Admin = pyxb.BIND('system name', 'Win32NT')
   rep.SentRequest = ???
```

How can i set value for attribute 'name111'?

Answer (score 0):

Since your xsd schema has multiple layers, you will need to inflate these one by one.

So your code should look like this:

```html
rep = Data_Requests()
rep.Admin = pyxb.BIND(SystemId = 'system name', OSName = 'Win32NT')

rep.SentRequest = pyxb.BIND()
rep.SentRequest.database = pyxb.BIND()
rep.SentRequest.database.datasetRequest = pyxb.BIND(name1111 = "example name")
```

Now you can test this with:

```
rep.toxml()
```

This should generate the following XML in accordance with your xsd schema:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Data_Requests>
  <Admin>
    <SystemId>system name</SystemId>
    <OSName>Win32NT</OSName>
  </Admin>
  <SentRequest>
    <database>
      <datasetRequest name1111="example name"/>
    </database>
  </SentRequest>
</Data_Requests>'
```